# OpenCV MPEG Video Streaming

Tags: opencv, video-streaming

I am developing peer-to-peer video streaming for network throughput test.
The network between two peers supports low bit-rate transfer.

I made simple python program for video streaming using OpenCV.
The program grabs video frame from Webcam and encodes it to JPEG then sends byte-stream to peer. It works well. But there is a problem against my purpose.
The size of one encoded-frame is around 5 Kbytes even if it encodes with lower JPEG quality.

To get smaller encoding result and better video quality, I am trying to use encoding with MPEG codec such as H264 or H263. Soon I found myself in difficulty.
No example exists in the Internet.
How can I change following code?

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
success, image = cap.read()
quality = 20 # quality 0 to 100. default:95
ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), quality])
# send(jpeg.tobytes())
```

Comment: What resolution are you streaming at? Often times jpeg is about the highest compression you can get. (5 kilobytes is EXTREMELY small per frame)

Comment: The resolution is 320x240. The size is len(jpeg.tobytes()) in above code.

Comment: Are you using greyscale or color? Also have you considered a binary image? (And then sending the binary image?) See http://answers.opencv.org/question/4423/how-to-create-a-binary-image-mat/

Comment: Thank you for your concerning on this topic. But I am afraid that it seems the referring binary image is uncompressed one. It could be huge in size.

Comment: In the example yes, they aren't compressing it. However, the jpeg format should be able to further compress a binary image as compared to a greyscale. Already, from what you are telling me you are doing roughly a 20x compression (EXTREMELY HIGH). Another thing you could try would be resize the image down to 160x120 (Should get you down to about 1.6-1.8 kbs)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer for real time encoding video frames from webcam!!
I realized that there is no way to do real-time MPEG encoding with OpenCV though OpenCV can save raw video frames into MPEG file.
I solved my problem using the ffmpeg opensource utility.
I let the ffmpeg encode a video frame and send it in UDP packet.
And my app received UDP packets and stream it on the test network. The average bit-rate of data, 320x240 5 FPS, is less than 25kbps(bits per seconds).

```
ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f dshow -i video="USB HD Webcam" -r 5 -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -b:v 25k -an -f h263 udp://127.0.0.1:10000
```